# How to convert UTC Timestamp to Timestamp with time zone

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, utc

I am using PostgreSql and having a column with datatype as Timestamp with time zone. But from the server its receiving a 'UTC Timestamp' value. I need to convert it to 'Timestamp with time zone' so that further comparisons can be done if required.

How can I do that. Please suggest me the ways to convert it and then store.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Which time zone do you want the UTC time stamp to be converted to? UTC _is_ (as far as the computer is concerned) already a time zone.

Comment: i need to convert UTC timestamp to "Timestamp with time zone". It is the datatype assigned for the column in my table.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`AT TIME ZONE` *operator*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) to covert

- `timestamps without time zone`s to `timestamps with time zone`s
- `timestamps with time zone`s to `timestamps without time zone`s

`timestamps without time zone` (aka. `timestamp`) always considered to be in UTC.